# Using camera slows the phone to a crawl, except the camera app

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-two

I have a OnePlus Two, flashed with Cyanogen Mod 12.1 nightly. I can use the camera, front or back, no problem in the actual camera app.

If I use a program that wants to open my camera (i.e. Google translate, Google authenticator, barcode scanner, etc), my phone goes so slow, that I need to reboot it by holding the power button until it comes back on. If I don't do it quickly, my phone starts getting very hot in my hand. This does not happen with the default camera app (com.android.camera2).

Is there a possible setting that I can change to make it work properly? I like the phone otherwise, but I may go back to the One, if this can't be resolved.

Comment: Are you certain that the issue isn't specific to the nightly build you are using?

Comment: @firelord it's happened for a few days now

Comment: Please try a stable build of this or a different ROM and report back

Comment: i also have been faced the same issue on samsung galaxy s3... I have found other build of cm 12.1 (Todko project) and I have flashed the rom and the problem solved...

Comment: @rishad it's a known issue with the current Rom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. There are no official builds, just garak's nightly, but it was not updated since November 2.